# Having an Echo'd <a> Tag Work as a Download Link in PHP Website

Tags: php, html, iis

So, I have a simple upload/download form on my PHP website. I have it set so that the files get uploaded to my upload folder within my IIS website. I want to have a link to download the file next to the table as such,

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBPYY.png)
My problem is with my code and I can't seem to figure out how to use the php variable inside the `<a>` tag as the `href=""`. Below is my code,

```
        <?php
        //path to directory to scan
        $directory = "uploads/";

        //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
        $images = glob($directory . "*.*");
         echo "<div class='col-md-12' align='center'><div class='col-sm-8'>
               <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
              <tr>
                <th width='80%'>Filename</th>
                <th width='20%'>Download</th>
              </tr>";
        //print each file name
        foreach($images as $image)
        {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $image;
        /*<a href="http://www.whatever.com/<?php echo $param; ?>">Click 
          Here</a>*/
        echo "</td><td><a href='<?php echo $image; ?>'>Download</a></td> 
             </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table></div></div>";

        ?>
```

And just in case you would like to see my upload code, here it is

```
<?php
 if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
  if($file_size > 2097152){
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads\\".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You're trying to echo within an echo. Just use the variable directly in the echo'd string.

Comment: So for example, echo "</td><td><a href='<?php  $image; ?>'>Download</a></td></tr>";

Comment: No.  You're already within a PHP control block. Don't open a new one.

Comment: So i did, echo "</td><td><a href='$image;'>Download</a></td></tr>"; and it downloaded stuff.txt however it said failed - no file. The file is in the folder and it got the correct name but it says no file.

Comment: Ahhhh I got it, the semi colon after $image was not needed and giving me the error. THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need concat

```
echo "</td><td><a href='".$image."'>Download</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: So when I did that it opened up the txt file in the browser instead of downloading it. It's a great step in the right direction because it can open the file but I would like to download it instead. Do you have any ideas? I also put "download" at the end of the opening <a> tag. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @Chris Just because you make the anchor named 'Download' doesn't mean the browser will. Text files open in browser by default when linked by url. You have to go to an url which changes the header response to instruct the browser to force-download instead of open inline.

Comment: I got it figured out, my solution was  echo "</td><td><a href='$image'>Download</a></td></tr>"; I had an unnecessary semi colon after $image. Thanks for the help